# powershell equivalent to get-argumentcompleter

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

`Register-ArgumentCompleter` is an incredibly useful function but I have a suspicion that overzealous use of it by some modules has caused my shell to slow down. I would like to see a list of all the *ArgumentCompleters* that are *Registered* in my Session.

I had an idea for how to write one, but it is overly complex and I have my doubts it would work, so if anyone knows of a solution already I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Jason Shirk's [TabExpansionPlusPlus Module](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the module [ImpliedReflection](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ImpliedReflection)

You can then use this line to read the argument completers. To access with without the ImpliedReflection module, use standard .net reflection.

`$ExecutionContext._invokeCommand._context.CustomArgumentCompleters.Keys`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible from looking at `Register-ArgumentCompleter`'s definition in the PowerShell 6 [code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/v6.0.0/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandCompletion/ExtensibleCompletion.cs#L91).

It seems that the actual dictionaries with the ScriptBlocks mapped to "command:parameter" keys are in `Context.CustomArgumentCompleters` which is an `ExecutionContext` (`internal` class) inherited from `InternalCommand`.
I don't see any interface to enumerate the ArgumentCompleter dictionaries from outside of `System.Management.Automation`.

Thus @BenH's suggestion to use [TabExpansionPlusPlus](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus) as a workaround might help diagnose as it appears to replace the builtin `Register-ArgumentCompleter` and `TabExpansion2` with a custom one that can be inspected (so if you load this module early enough you can look at modules that might be registering a lot of completer). However if something is invoking `System.Management.Automation.RegisterArgumentCompleterCommand` directly you might need to attach a debugger.